# Connecting to a node server on mac from a local network

Tags: networking, ip, webserver, localhost

I want to test my app from an iphone locally, so I tried to access the ip of the mac it is running on (on the same network, and including the port: `192.168.1.101:3456`) and it is not working.

The internet sharing is enabled in system prefs and I tried disabling the firewall and even using Little snitch to allow all connections to node app. Still not working. Any ideas?

(I am not interested in payed tunneling services)